# Improve parallelism in spark sql

Tags: python, concurrency, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have the below code. I am using pyspark 1.2.1 with python 2.7 (cpython)

```
for colname in shuffle_columns:
    colrdd = hive_context.sql('select %s from %s' % (colname, temp_table))
    # zip_with_random_index is expensive
    colwidx = zip_with_random_index(colrdd).map(merge_index_on_row)
    (hive_context.applySchema(colwidx, a_schema)
        .registerTempTable(a_name))
```

The thing about this code is that it only operates on one column at a time. I have enough nodes in my cluster that I could be operating on many columns at once. **Is there a way to do this in spark?** What if I used threads or the like - could I kick off multiple of the `registerTempTable` (and associated collection operations) in parallel that way?

Comment: I had a somewhat similar issue (With Scala though). You can create an RDD out of `shuffle_columns` and use `.foreach`, that way spark will take care of the parallelism.

Comment: @markiz Is that right, though? The body of the loop involves calls to the HiveContext and other rdds; those things can't be distributed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the below does not work well. It works in the sense that all of the individual iterations execute. Unfortunately, subsequent calls to the `hive_context` object fail due to a nullpointer exception.

---

This is possible with `concurrent.futures`:

```
from concurrent import futures

def make_col_temptable(colname):
    colrdd = hive_context.sql('select %s from %s' % (colname, temp_table))
    # zip_with_random_index is expensive
    colwidx = zip_with_random_index(colrdd).map(merge_index_on_row)
    (hive_context.applySchema(colwidx, a_schema)
        .registerTempTable(a_name))

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    futures.wait([executor.submit(make_col_temptable, colname) for colname in shuffle_columns])
```