# How to read multiple tables parallel in apache Spark?

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark

i'm new use apache spark

i have done build recommended system using Mllib in apache spark

I read 3 table from postgresSql (tb_a, tb_b, tb_c)

but i have problem for execution time, i think it's because spark read 3 table sequential

How make spark read table in pararel from postgresql ?

thx

NB : i use python in spark

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improve parallelism in spark sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217242/improve-parallelism-in-spark-sql)

Comment: Generally speaking increasing parallelism won't help unless your database backend and network can handle the load. Do you need live data? If not just `COPY` your tables to the distributed file system of your choice. If you do you, use replication and make sure each table is accessed using different DB server.